# Android support EditTextPreference input type

Tags: android, android-support-library, edittextpreference

Is there any way to specify the input method type for `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference`?

Comment: [Related Android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185164), no fix in sight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now one can use [Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) library.
Fixed `EditTextPreference` forwards the XML attributes (like `inputType`) to the `EditText`, just like the original preference did.

Comment: This library is far superior to android.support.v7.preference. More feature rich, and easier to Theme.

Comment: AndroidX has a `setOnBindEditTextListener` method which can be used to work around the issue. You can change the EditText input type from within the listener.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/EditTextPreference#setOnBindEditTextListener(androidx.preference.EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener)

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to use a third party library, it is possible to specify a layout to the EditTextPreference

```
<EditTextPreference android:defaultValue="0"
                        android:key="some_key"
                        android:title="Title"
                        android:dialogLayout="@layout/preference_edit_text"/>
```

Then in res/layout/preference_edit_text.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@android:id/edit"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:singleLine="true" 
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          android:layout_marginStart="21dp" 
          android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please note that the edit text id must be : `@android:id/edit`
but then you are free to use whatever you want inside the `android:inputType` field

I'm sure there's a better way to align the EditText rather than using `21dp` margins
but at least it works

Comment: Thanks a lot. Accepted answer offers to use 3rd party lib. More over it's not actually for android-support library but rather for androidX, which is not acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version of the answer from Cory Charlton, transfered to Jetpack preferences and written in Kotlin:

```
 import android.content.Context
 import android.content.SharedPreferences
 import android.text.InputType
 import android.util.AttributeSet
 import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference
 
 
 class EditIntegerPreference : EditTextPreference {
     constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
         setInputMethod()
     }
 
     constructor(context: Context?, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attributeSet) {
         setInputMethod()
     }
 
     constructor(context: Context?, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
         context,
         attributeSet,
         defStyle
     ) {
         setInputMethod()
     }
 
     override fun getText(): String =
         try {
             java.lang.String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0))
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             "0"
         }
 
     override fun setText(text: String?) {
         try {
             if (text != null) {
                 sharedPreferences?.edit()?.putInt(key, text.toInt())?.apply()
                 summary = text
             } else {
                 sharedPreferences?.remove(key)
                 summary = ""
             }
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             sharedPreferences?.remove(key)
             summary = ""
         }
     }
 
     override fun onSetInitialValue(defaultValue: Any?) {
         val defaultValueInt: Int =
                 when (defaultValue){
                     is Int -> defaultValue
                     is String -> try {defaultValue.toInt()} catch (ex: java.lang.Exception){0}
                     else -> 0
                 }
 
         text = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValueInt).toString()
     }
 
     private fun setInputMethod() {
         setOnBindEditTextListener {
             it.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
         }
     }
 
     fun SharedPreferences.remove(key: String) = edit().remove(key).apply()
 }
```

Comment: What if a  `PreferenceDatastore` is used? How can we then bind the above to a custom `DataStore`?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** The previous answers below were built on the stock `android.preference.EditTextPreference` and unfortunately don't work for the `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference`.

In the `android.preference.EditTextPreference` the `EditText` control is created programmatically and the `AttributeSet` from the `Preference` is passed to it.

[`android.preference.EditTextPreference` Source:](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/EditTextPreference.java)

```
public EditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mEditText = new EditText(context, attrs);

    // Give it an ID so it can be saved/restored
    mEditText.setId(com.android.internal.R.id.edit);

    /*
     * The preference framework and view framework both have an 'enabled'
     * attribute. Most likely, the 'enabled' specified in this XML is for
     * the preference framework, but it was also given to the view framework.
     * We reset the enabled state.
     */
    mEditText.setEnabled(true);
}
```

White allows us to set the `inputType` on the `Preference` itself and have it pass through to the `EditText`. Unfortunately the `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference` appears to create the `EditText` in the `Layout`

See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185164) for ideas on working around this:

> Just wanted to let you know that subclassing EditTextPreferenceDialogFragment and overriding onAddEditTextToDialogView as well as overriding PreferenceFragmentCompat#onDisplayPreferenceDialog to show that subclass as needed seems to be working fine, thanks for the help.

---

Create your own class that extends the `EditTextPreference` and set it there.

Here's my `EditIntegerPreference` class:

```
public class EditIntegerPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    public EditIntegerPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditIntegerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public EditIntegerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);

        getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        getEditText().setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        try {
            return String.valueOf(getSharedPreferences().getInt(getKey(), 0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return getSharedPreferences().getString(getKey(), "0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        try {
            if (getSharedPreferences() != null) {
                getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt(getKey(), Integer.parseInt(text)).commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: This catch stinks!
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        getEditText().setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

        if (restoreValue) {
            getEditText().setText(getText());
        } else {
            super.onSetInitialValue(restoreValue, defaultValue != null ? defaultValue : "");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that it is possible to add the `inputType` attribute to the the `EditTextPreference`

```
android:inputType="number"
```

The reason I didn't go this route is that I wanted my preference to get stored as an `Integer` and not a `String`

Comment: Unfortunately `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference` doesn't contain `getEditText()` method.

Comment: @ivkil is there a particular reason you need `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference`? I ask because `android.preference.EditTextPreference` has existed since API level 1.

Comment: Yep. To provide settings for my app, I'm using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

Comment: @ivkil bummer I hadn't used `PreferenceFragmentCompat` yet. Not sure why the support implementation is a regression from the stock `Preference`. I'll see if I can find anything else.

Comment: @ivkil I updated my answer with possible, although more involved, solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround for Kotlin + DataStore + androidx.Preference

##### Disclaimer!

Probably this isn't the way to do it!
Ideally one should only:

- set the input to int
- override in a `DataStore` class: `putInt`/`getInt`

---

### Extension Function

In my case I had a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, so:

```
fun PreferenceFragmentCompat.setNumericInput(
@StringRes prefRes: Int, initialValue: String) {

  val preference = findPreference(getString(prefRes)) as EditTextPreference?

  preference?.setOnBindEditTextListener { editText ->
    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or 
      InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED

    // set the initial value: I read it from the DataStore and then
    // pass it as the 2nd argument to setNumericInput.
    // BTW, I do store stringPreferenceKeys, as it's the putString method 
    // that get's triggered
    if (editText.text.isEmpty()) editText.setText(initialValue)

    editText.setSelection(editText.text.length) // put cursor at the end
  }

  // to use it in the summary do something like:
  preference?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { it, newValue ->
    it.summary = "updated: $newValue"
    true
  }
}
```

Also, in my Activity that extends `BaseSettingsActivity` I
replace the management from `SharedPreferences` using:

```
preferenceManager.preferenceDataStore = dataStoreCvLogger
```